# Looking for a short story involving robotic proxy warfare on the moon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots, warfare, moon

War was banished from Earth, and instead operated by proxy on the Moon. Belligerent nations would each send robots (not necessarily androids) to the moon to compete for supremacy in the given conflict.

- The short story detailed a "world war" that was something like WW XVII or some other number well beyond II or III.
- The mechanisms by which they attacked each other were interesting; things like interfering with each others ability to isolate or dissipate waste heat while in vacuum.

I believe I originally read it in an Analog Magazine that would have originally been published in the 1970s or early 1980s.

Comment: That sounds cool, hope someone answers.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Stanislaw Lems "Peace on Earth" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_on_Earth_(novel)) - but it is not a short story, and the other things don't quite match either.

Comment: Definitely not Peace on Earth, but that deliciously hilarious.

Comment: Sounds a bit like "Robot Jox", but classier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be thinking of "A Short History of World War LXXVIII", by Roy L. Prosterman, published in Analog in 1977.

> "After 2025, however, it became possible to transfer the status of
>   fighting to Luna, and this is where all subsequent wars have been
>   fought."

Comment: Woo hoo!  Sadly though, never anthologized http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50251

Comment: @OrganicMarble Happily, that issue of *Analog* is not rare: Abe.com lists 28 copies for sale, starting at $2 + postage. The current issue (they still publish, don't they?) probably costs twice as much.

Comment: I miss the stacks at my university.  They had the full runs of all the major sf magazines.

Comment: I'm curious, Paul, how did you happen to figure that out? Even with the strings you provide, Google is completely useless for me as per finding any mention of that story anywhere. Did you recently read that issue?

Comment: @Michael Mol As you may have guessed, I had to go to the original source materials.